# Launching QGIS with specific user profile

Tags: qgis, profile

By default, when you launch QGIS, it shows the most recent user profile you worked with. It's not convenient because I have settings in various languages and locales and have to switch frequently between profiles.

Is it possible to start QGIS specifying the desired profile using a command for CLI in macOS, Windows, and Linux?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the command line you can start QGIS with the `--profile` option:

```
qgis-bin.exe --profile spanish
```

will start QGIS and load my `spanish` profile on Windows.

Comment: I changed your solution to fit macOS, which worked for me: `open -a qgis3.14.app --args --profile custom_en`

Answer (score 0):

Open the Active Profile Folder to navigate to where the profiles are stored and go one level up to the root of the profiles.

This can be found in Settings | User Profiles.

There you will find `profiles.ini` that needs to be modified to reflect the name of the profile you want to load by default.

In order to be able to modify this file first replace the `ini` extension to `ini_`.

Open with a text editor and modify.

Then fix the extension.