# Can QGIS ask for the preferred user profile on startup?

Tags: qgis, gui, user-interface

I'm using QGIS user profiles for different tasks and would like to choose the right one  at QGIS startup - is that possible?

I know how to set the default profile by editing the profiles.ini in QGIS profile folder, but I would like to choose it on QGIS start.

I also found that solution by starting qgis in a specific profile via command line: [Launching QGIS with specific user profile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374226/launching-qgis-with-specific-user-profile)

Comment: So, a little batch file with a user prompt with your QGIS different profiles would meet the need?

Comment: Sure, that would meet my need ;-) I'm running Linux (Mint)

Comment: QGIS 3.32 will do this

Comment: @bugmenot123 probably worth another answer as here in the comments, it risks to be overlooked.

Comment: No time, just bumped into this question while searching for other things. Feel welcome to add it!

Comment: see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/437368/93097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small shell script that list your QGIS profiles and let the user choose the desired one.

Don't forget to do a `chmod +x your_file.sh` to execute it in a terminal.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM"
echo "MMMMMMMMNOdlc::::clxONMMMMMMMM"
echo "MMMMMW0l'            'l0WMMMMM"
echo "MMMMXl.   'cxkOOOxl'   .oXMMMM"
echo "MMMXc   .dXMMMMMMMMXd.   cNMMM"
echo "MMMk.  .dWMMXkxxkKWMWd.  .kMMM"
echo "MMWd   .OMMWd.  .:kNMO.   dWMM"
echo "MMMk.  .dWMMK:..cxlokk;  .kMMM"
echo "MMMXc   .oXMMN0kKo   .cl;oXMMM"
echo "MMMMXl.   'lxO000x;.   .l0WMMM"
echo "MMMMMW0l.        .co;    ,0MMM"
echo "MMMMMMMWXOdl:;;;::o0Nk:..;0MMM"
echo "MMMMMMMMMMMMMWWWMMMMMMWNNNWMMM"
echo ""

QGIS_USER_DIR=~/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/
PROFILES=$(ls -l $QGIS_USER_DIR | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}')
OPTIONS=($PROFILES "Quit")
VALID_PROFILES=$(echo $PROFILES | sed -e "s/[ ]/|/g")

PS3="Choose your QGIS profile: "
select opt in "${OPTIONS[@]}"
do
    CHOICE=$opt
    if [[ $opt == "" ]]; then
        CHOICE="_invalid_profile_"
    elif [[ $VALID_PROFILES =~ $opt ]]; then
        CHOICE="_valid_profile_"
    fi
    case $CHOICE in
        "_valid_profile_" )
            qgis --profile $opt
            break
            ;;
        Quit)
            break
            ;;
        *) echo "invalid option $REPLY";;
    esac
done
```